# What can cause Scripting.FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile() to fail?

Tags: javascript, windows, activex, windows-scripting

We've got a (non-web) application that uses Javascript to extend its functionality.  At one point, there's a script command that creates a `Scripting.FIleSystemObject` ActiveX object and calls `OpenTextFile` on it to read a configuration file.

The file's always there, always in the same place.  Most of the time, this works, but I've got intermittent reports of it failing with a "File Not Found" error.  The file isn't going anywhere, so does anyone know what else can cause it to fail?  Could it perhaps be a concurrency/permissions error, and so it only happens when two files try to open it at the same time?  That's the only thing I can think of, but that shouldn't return "File Not Found"...

Comment: Is there any code that writes/makes changes to this file?

Comment: @user1090190: No, the file's read-only.